# Java - Assign unicode apostrophe to char

Tags: java, unicode

I want to assign the value of aphostrophe to a char:

```
char a = '\'';
```

However I would like to use the unicode version of apostrophe (\u0027) to keep it consistent with my code:

```
char a = '\u0027';
```

But doing it this way gives an error saying "unclosed character literal".

How can I do this assignment while still having the unicode code in the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason `\u0027` doesn't work is that the unicode escape is handled *very early* by the compiler, and of course, it ends up being `'` — which terminates the literal. The compiler actually sees this:

```
char a = ''';
```

...which naturally is a problem. The JLS talks about this in relation to line feeds and such in [§3.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4) (*Character Literals*).

Frankly, I think you're best off writing

```
char a = '\'';
```

...but `char` is a numeric type, so you could do this:

```
char a = 0x0027;
```

Of course, you *could* do this:

```
char a = "\u0027".charAt(0);
```

...but I think we can all agree that's a bit overkill. ;-)

Oooh, or check out [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693486/157247): `char a = '\u005c\u0027';` (`\u005c` is, of course, a backslash — so the compiler sees `'\''`).

Comment: The main problem is that `\u0027` is processed really early by the compiler, so this may end up being his best (maybe even only) option.

Comment: Also, check out the footnotes at the bottom of the JLS you just linked in your edit. It says you can't use something like `'\u000a'` because it gets processed into a newline before the class is even compiled.

Comment: @Brian: LOL overlapping edit and comment, refresh the page. ;-)

Comment: why does it need to be any  better?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey now, my comment was a full _1 minute and 38 seconds_ before your edit :D

Comment: I meant what's wrong with your solution -- why does it need to be any better?  I see nothing wrong

Comment: @Brian: I must have been typing slowly. ;-)

Comment: I love Greg's suggestion. It makes me feel like I'm in The Matrix.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this as well

```
char a = '\u005c\u0027';
```

where **\u005c** is the Unicode for \

Comment: LOL! I love it. And given the OP's reason for wanting to use `\u0027` in the first place, a pretty good idea...

Answer (score 1):

before javac does anything else, it first convert all \u#### to a char. so your code is equivalent to

```
char a = ''';
```

that's why it doesn't compile.

\u#### is not just for char/string literals, you can use it anywhere, e.g. in variable names.

however, people rarely use non latin chars in identifiers; if someone does, he'll probably use his native charset, and he won't need \u#### either.

therefore we never really see \u#### anywhere other than in char/string literals, this gives the wrong impression to the unsuspected.

if there's time machine, we should probably kill this feature, since it's confusing and it's not used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, indeed an overkill though:

```
char c = "\u0027".charAt(0);
```